# Ignition fault, not cranking Renault Master Ambulance 2006

Tags: ignition, renault

After some strange behaviour from the locks, the ignition of my Renault master, 2006, ex-ambulance, will no longer crank the starter motor when the key is turned. Replaced battery in key lock remote control, but no difference. Is this the imobilizer? How can I disable the imbolilizer? I'm stuck in a foreign country.